# How to print pass array from controller to view and print it in view

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

This is my controller:-

```
public function index(){        
            $img_path = $this->DBClassName->myDbMethod($users);//fetching results from database.

            $i = 1;
            foreach($img_path as $row){
              $img_name[] = $row->image_name;
              $i++;
            }
            /*print_r($img_name); */ //Array ( [0] => userA.jpg [1] => userB.jpg [2] => userC.jpg [3] => userD.jpg [4] => userE.jpg )
            $this->load-view('welcome', $img_name);

    }
```

Now how to count the number of items in **$img_name** and *print* all the items of **$img_name** *array* in *welcome(view)*

Comment: Function `count` counts number of items in array.

Answer (score 0):

Get the query result and pass it straight to the view

```
public function index() {
    $data['img_path'] = $this->DBClassName->myDbMethod($users);
    $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}
```

And in the view to get all the image names do the following:

```
foreach ($img_path as $row){
    echo $row->image_name;
}
```

No need for the count. (If it is required for something else than displaying the data then you can get the count with "count($img_path);" as u_molder said.

Answer (score -1):

First Assign the get query result to $data['img_path'] array and pass directly to your view like below code:-

```
public function index() {
    $data['img_path'] = $this->DBClassName->myDbMethod($users);
    $this->load->view('welcome', $data);
}
```

And in your view print, the same data will available in $img_path array.
So that you can print the data like below loop:-

```
foreach ($img_path as $row){
    echo $row->image_name;
}
```

Comment: Helps to sometimes read the topic and see what has already been posted as a response.